# Telegram WebApp: loading animated icon

Tags: telegram, progressive-web-apps

I've made some WebApp on Telegram and that's fine. When my WebApp is loading, there is a small grey animated icon (like a small robot).
But I notice that when the "demonstration WebApp Durger King" is loading, the animated icon is different (small hamburger).

How can I change the animated icon for my WebApps?

Thanks

Comment: @acidernt Unfortunatly no....